# Thymeleaf template not working with inline JS

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, thymeleaf

I'm hitting a problem when I want to extract my function to a script inside html. If its written like this it works:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" 
        onkeypress="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');"
        placeholder="Search for manufacturers.." />
```

But if I try to make it as a function inside script like this, it just doesn't execute:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" 
        onkeypress="myFunction()"
        placeholder="Search for manufacturers.." />
```

Function:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    function myFunction() {
    alert("You pressed a key inside the input field");
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: did you have the chance to try my answer?

Comment: I did, it works, I'm dumb and thank you :)

Comment: haha no worries, everybody have this kind of mistakes, its super common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a small typo.

Didnt close the function

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    function myFunction() {
        alert("You pressed a key inside the input field");
    }
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are developing on spring boot, check this.
Did you set this `spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5` on application.properties 
 just change configuration in application.properties to `spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5` or delete it by default

```
#spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
```